# How to include full objects in React Testing Library snapshots?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a React component that accepts an object as a prop:

```
const Button = ({ customCss }) => (
  <div><AnotherChildComponent customCss={customCss} /></div>
)
```

In Jest (v29) I want a snapshot test to cover that I pass on the object to the child component:

```
describe('<Button />', () => {
    let elem

    beforeAll(() => {
        const renderResult = render(<Button customCss={{ color: 'blue' }} />);
        elem = renderResult.container.firstChild
    })

    it('should have snapshot', () => {
        expect(elem).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```

However my snapshot does not show the entire object and it just calls `.toString()` on my object:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1,

exports[`<Button /> should have snapshot 1`] = `<div>
  <AnotherChildComponent
    customcss="[object Object]"
  />
</div>
`;
```

How can I change Jest/Testing Library to `JSON.stringify` my prop instead of `toString`ing it?

@testing-library/react@^14

Answer (score 1):

You can configure jest with a custom serializer for your snapshots

- In your config: [snapshotSerializers](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#snapshotserializers-arraystring)
- Or in each test that needs it: [expect.addSnapshotSerializer](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectaddsnapshotserializerserializer)

Effectively, you can provide the logic to produce the snapshot's output, so if you want to use `JSON.stringify`, you can do that in your own implementation.

...or, you can use `JSON.stringify` inline if you find its output is sufficient:

```
// become a three-space indentation monster like me
// ...or don't, and change the third param to the number of spaces you want
expect(JSON.stringify(elem, undefined, 3)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

See [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more info on its signature